# SAP XSLT: Test value from choicefield's selection

Tags: xslt, dropdown

I am an ABAP developer and very new to XSL coding. Currently, I am having a problem with which I do not find any help on the Internet. I searched a lot and for more than four days tried things in many ways and decided to post here.

I am not even sure whether this is possible in SAP XSLT or XSLT in General.

Problem Description:
I got a choice field. Based on values selected in that choice field I have to Display texts in different text fields.

For example, my code Looks like

```
    <choicefield id="TEST" refname="CH2" title="Objekts">
  <choice>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="01"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="title">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Objekt 1', ' ')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="meta:char1">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Objekt 1 - Char 1', ' ')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="meta:char2">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Objekt 1 - Char 2', ' ')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </choice>
  <choice>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="02"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="title">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Objekt', ' 2')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="meta:char1">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Objekt 2', ' - Char 1')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="meta:char2">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Objekt 2', ' - Char 2')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </choice>
</choicefield>
<textfield id="TXT1" titel="Text 1">
  <xsl:value-of select="./oppc:choicefield[@refname='CH2']//oppc:choice[@selected='true']/@id"/>
</textfield>
```

First of all, I cannot store the selected value in a variable. Tried different kinds of syntax, nothing worked. Suggestions are welcome.
Tried displaying directly in the text field but it does not work. The text field is always empty.

Also tried through Attribute text.expression="$CH2.selection.id", but the problem with this is that the field is not editable after using this Attribute.

please help me to find a solution or an alternative.

Comment: ...and what might a "choicefield" be? I get the impression that you're expecting XSLT to process some kind of user interaction...?

Comment: Choicefield is a kind of Dropdown from which user can select a particular value/choice.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to process user interaction. Based on user's choice, I want to Display some text in text field. Is that not possible using XSLT?

Comment: It's not what it is intended to do. XSLT is a transformation language that will help you to transform one XML data structure into another. It is not concerned with what the XML structure might represent.

Comment: I think the problem is that most of us don't understand the context in which your stylesheet operates, and you are writing the question as if we do. It would help if you can reduce it to a description of the input XML that your stylesheet is processing, the output XML (or HTML) that it is generating, and the logic for transforming one to the other.

Comment: You say you can't "store the selected value in a variable". But we don't know what the selected value is, or why you want to store it in a variable. We also can't tell you what you did wrong unless you tell us what you did. Telling us that you tried everything and nothing worked is not helpful: tell us one thing that you did, and tell us exactly how it failed.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your Responses. I came to know that it is not possible to do this using XSLT "Performing dynamic Actions like processing or validating users interaction" in XSLT. one of my colleauges explained me how it works.so i can't really refer any links here...